# How come if $X$ is a Geometric random variable, then $P(X > x) = q^x?$

Tags: probability

I know that $P(X > x) = 1 - P(X \leq x)$ via the definition of the complement, but how come this is also equal to $q^x$ where $q$ is the probability of failure in a trial in a Geometric distribution? How does $q^x$ account for all cases where $X > x$? Can someone explain this to me?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \sim $ Geometric$(p)$ then we know the CDF of $X$ is $F(k) = 1- (1-p)^k = 1-q^k$

So then what does $1- F(k) = P(X > k)$ mean then? It means at least $k$-many trials have failed.

Symbolically we have $P(X > k) = 1- P(X \le k) = 1 - [1 - (1-p)^k] = 1- [1-q^k] = q^k$

This is for the definition of Geometric distribution supported on $k \in \{1,2,3,4, \ldots\} = \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$

Answer (score 5):

Another equivalent way to say that

- the first success to occur after $x$ trials,

is

- you must failed at the first $x$ trials

What happens after $x$ doesn't matter.

Comment: Stripped of all jargon (+1)

Answer (score 2):

$X>x$ means that your first $x$ trials were all failures. The probability of this is clearly $q^x$.